# Inserting data from form to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am using PHP to send data from a form to mysql database, when I use this code:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
pelak VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

it works perfectly, but when I use:

```
$field_table = $_POST['phone'];
$sql = "CREATE TABLE '{$field_table}' (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
pelak VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

it create table in phpmyadmin but gives an error:

> "#1146 - Table 'username.table_name' doesn't exist"

Comment: Are you creating a new table every time the form is sumbitted?

Comment: yes, one table for each user, it worked till yesterday.

Comment: Why would you do that? This is a really bad way to do things. You should create one table and create one record in that table for each user.

Comment: yes i know, there is not any other way? because after user singning up i want to read his/her data, but i don't know how to search inside one table.

Comment: you can search using `SELECT` command `SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = $id`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in comments